# Neo4j 3.0.6 and neo4j-ogm 2.0.5 - Create duplicate data on database

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I have a problem with neo4j database. When I try to init data, it should be just create one sample data but sometimes when I try to init data, it create double sample data. There is no trace about calling second times. This is the Config of my Neo4j

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.neo.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Neo4jConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {
    @Override
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        // with domain entity base package(s)
        return new SessionFactory("com.example.neo.model", "BOOT-INF.classes.com.example.neo.model");
    }

    // needed for session in view in web-applications
    @Override
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public Session getSession() throws Exception {
        return super.getSession();
    }
}
```

This is how I called my function

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/initCurrency")
public ModelAndView initCurrency() {
    initializationService.initCurrency();

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    return model;
}
```

This is the initializationService function

```
private String[][] currencyList = {
        { "USD", "7.5" },
        { "DKK", "1" },
        { "AFN", "1"},{ "EUR", "1"},{ "ALL", "1"},{ "DZD", "1"},{ "USD", "1"},{ "AOA", "1"},{ "XCD", "1"},
        { "ARS", "1"},{ "AMD", "1"},{ "AWG", "1"},{ "SHP", "1"},{ "AUD", "1"},{ "AZN", "1"},{ "BSD", "1"},
        { "BHD", "1"},{ "BDT", "1"},{ "BBD", "1"}
}
@Override
public void initCurrency() {
    for (String[] currency : currencyList) {
        Currency existCurrency = currencyService.findByName(currency[0]);

        if (existCurrency == null) {
            existCurrency = new Currency(currency[0], Double.valueOf(currency[1]));
            currencyService.save(existCurrency);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should add a uniqueness constraint on the currency code - both to prevent duplicates, and shed light on what is going wrong.

Comment: @JasperBlues I already add unique Id and prevent duplicate by using findByName. If there is exist CUrrency, its should be skip the saving code. But when I check neo4j database, There are double data with differnt unique Id.

Comment: What Jasper means is you should make the name of the currency unique, using something like `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Currency) ASSERT n.name IS UNIQUE` (supposing `USD` goes in the `name` property of the `Currency` label). The application wouldn't be able to create 2 nodes with the same currency name, the second one would fail and you'd find an exception in your logs.

Comment: @FrankPavageau Ahh. thank you for the explanation. Actually Currency is  one of my class, so I need to make every class in my database have an unique data, for example prperty Name, right?

Comment: @FrankPavageau But actually, if there is same Data, I already prevent it with my code if(existCUrrency == null). But why sometimes it can bypass that conditional and make duplicate data?

Comment: The entities that have a unique identifier (name, uuid, whatever) should have a constraint (which creates an index and speeds up the lookup too!). It's not the case of all entities: if entity `B` only exists in the context of entity `A`, it might not have a globally unique property. E.g. if you have `Version` nodes related to `Software` nodes, the versions are not globally unique, both `Neo4j` and `Windows` can have version `3.0`.

Comment: Your code only prevents duplicates in the case of sequential calls to the init service. If you have concurrent calls, it's a race condition when the threads execution is interleaved: thread A checks it doesn't exist, thread B checks it doesn't exist, thread A creates the currency, thread B also creates the currency.

Comment: Yes, i noticed that It must be cause of thread. But, I only run it once and not call the function again and only 1 thread run to executed that.

Comment: @FrankPavageau care to turn your advice into an answer? We can provide links to index creation docs too. (Btw, we're working on an annotation to create indexes in code - not available yet though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reliable way to avoid duplicates is to have an actual [unicity constraint](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#query-constraints) on the property:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Currency) ASSERT n.name IS UNIQUE;
```

There's no way in SDN 4.[0-2] (yet) to create such a constraint from the model (there was in SDN 3.x with the `@Indexed` or `@Indexed(unique = true)` annotation), so you'll have to run the query independently (for example using [Liquigraph](http://www.liquigraph.org)!).

Doing a lookup to guard the creation is not enough in a concurrent environment (sequential calls are OK), because there's no lock between the read and the write, which can result in the following scenario with an interleaved execution:

- Thread A checks the existence, doesn't find a node
- Thread B checks the existence, doesn't find a node either
- Thread A creates a currency node named "USB"
- Thread B creates another currency node with the same name

Since you end up with duplicates, 2 concurrent calls *are happening*. A load balancer with a really short timeout and configured to retry? Activate HTTP logs, add some logging in the Spring controller or service, capture the traffic with `tcpdump`, etc. It will be easier to isolate the second call once the unicity constraint is active, since you'll get an exception.

Comment: Yeah. Its because 2 threads run simultaneously, thats why Its create duplicate data. Its like your explanation. ANyway Thank you for this information, really helpful.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `@Index` and `@Index(unique = true)` is supported in OGM `2.1.0-SNAPSHOT`: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/pull/243